# mysql count for same column but two counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a count on the same column having different status, how can i do it, i tried but i am running into bunch of issues

```
SELECT
    distinct tblsmsgroups.GroupName,
    tblsmsphones.PhoneNumber,
    tblsmsphones.GroupID,
    count(case when status = 1 then) as active
FROM
    tblsmscustomers,
    tblsmsgroups
INNER JOIN tblsmsphones 
    ON tblsmsgroups.groupID = tblsmsphones.GroupID
```

status = 1 then active how many, and status = 0 , then counts of how many, i am still stuck at the syntactical difference as to how can i do, any idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT 
    tblsmsgroups.GroupName,
    tblsmsphones.PhoneNumber,
    tblsmsphones.GroupID,
    sum(status = 1) as active_count,
    sum(status != 1) as inactive_count
FROM
    tblsmscustomers ,
    tblsmsgroups
    INNER JOIN tblsmsphones ON tblsmsgroups.groupID = tblsmsphones.GroupID
GROUP BY GroupName, PhoneNumber, GroupID
```

Comment: In MySQL, you can just `SUM(status=1)`, and mixing JOIN styles can lead to problems

Comment: I didn't come up with the join, it was there in the original question. Fair point on the sum expression though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to add stuff up, you want a `group by`.

If you want to join tables, you want `join` -- never use commas for that purpose.

That suggest something like:

```
SELECT g.GroupName, p.PhoneNumber, p.GroupID,
       SUM(status = 1) as active,
       SUM(status = 0) as not_active
FROM tblsmsgroups g JOIN
     tblsmsphones p
     ON g.groupID = p.GroupID JOIN
     tblsmscustomers c
     ON c.customerID = p.customerID   -- have to guess the JOIN condition here
GROUP BY g.GroupName, p.PhoneNumber, p.GroupID;
```

Note:  Your question does not have enough information to understand the join conditions between the three tables; the above is a reasonable guess.